# Scala URLClassLoader ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, scala, protocol-buffers

I need to load some class at runtime out of a jar file, but every time I try, I get a ClassNotFoundException. I created the jar file using jar command. In addition, person class is generated from the protocol buffer message.

Contents of protocol buffer msg:

```
package testing;
option java_outer_classname = "AddressBookProtos";
option java_package = "com.sample";

message AddressBook {
  repeated Persons person = 1;
}

message Persons {
    required string name =1;
}
```

Scala File:

```
object loaderTest extends App {

val classLoader = new URLCLassLoader(Array(new File("C:\\TEMP\\address.jar").toURI.toURL), this.getClass().getClassLoader())

val personClass = classLoader.loadClass("com.sample.AddressBookProtos$Persons")

}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sample.AddressBookProtos$Persons
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.ms.qaTools.protobuf.specs.loaderTest$delayedInit$body.apply(loaderTest.scala:34)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:60)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:30)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:60)
    at com.ms.qaTools.protobuf.specs.loaderTest$.main(loaderTest.scala:10)
    at com.ms.qaTools.protobuf.specs.loaderTest.main(loaderTest.scala)

Comment: Have you opened up the jar to make sure this class exists under the package you are indicating it should be under?

Comment: Yes, I did run the jar xf command to check if the folder sturcture (com.sample) and file exists ( AddressBookProtos.java).

Comment: The `.java` file doesn't help. You need to have the compiled `.class` file in there, in the right package (`com.sample`).